# Collapse Panel on postback in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit, panels

I have two panels with a gridview in each. I want to expand panels on pageload but if I collapse one of the panel later I want the planel to stay collapsed on postback when I update gridview in other panel. I am trying to do this without javascript, is there a easy way to do this?

Code structure looks like this:

```
<asp:Panel id="1" runat="server">  //panel 1
       <table>
           <tr><td>
               <asp:GridView id="grid1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
           </td> </tr> </table>
 </panel>

 <asp:Panel id="Panel2" runat="server">  //Panel2
         <table>
            <tr><td>
                <asp:GridView id="Grid2" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
            </td> </tr> </table>
</panel>
```

Comment: Wrap the gridview in theyr own updatepanel. this way only the content inside the updatepanel will update resulting in not closing or opening the panels

Comment: What do you mean you want the panel *open* or *closed*?

Comment: @wazz by open and close I mean Expand & Collapse.

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan Can't wrap grids in the their own update panels because there is parent panel and parent updatepanels which has other controls that I don't to change.